# how to make full scrolling text - ios

Tags: html, ios, xml, ionic-framework

Once I open the application, there will have a scrolling text. I would like to make it scroll the whole text. what just happening, it just scrolling a part of the text. If i count the text included the spacing. It just appear until 100 words. I just want it to scrolling the whole words. what should i do?

Here is my code. (style.xml)

```
.scroll-left {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.scroll-left p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    /* Apply animation to this element */
    -moz-animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
    animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        /* Browser bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        /* Browser bug fix */
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Browser bug fix */
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        /* Browser bug fix */
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

Here is my html. (a.html)

```
<div class="scroll-left">
  <p>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
  </p>
</div>
```

this is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/aishahismail/pen/VjLoMW)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property to your `p` tag with `!important`:

```css
.scroll-left p {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

This property tells your browser how to handle white spaces inside the element. When using `nowrap` value, sequences of whitespace collapse into a single whitespace and text does not wrap to the next line. It continues on the same line until a `<br>` tag is encountered.

And using `!important` will override other values being set by other classes. In your particular case, `white-space: normal;` is being set by the iconic framework. You can check it using [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) in your browser. This is how I solved this issue.

Comment: it work in my codepen, but when i used it in my application(ionic framework) it being like [this](http://codepen.io/aishahismail/pen/YWypaR)

Comment: white-space: nowrap !important really do work :) thank you. but another problem came. so i need to open another question.